# Bash script to search whole word and replace

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

How do I search and replace whole words.

I have written a script like this

```
Profile="panicA2 panicA1 panicA0 gasleakB0"
Bypass="0 panicA1 gasleakB0"
Current="$Profile"
for Bypass_final in $Bypass ; do
    Current=${Current/$Bypass_final/ }
done
```

The expected output from my script was `panicA2   panicA0`

but my output is `panicA2   panicA` the 0 in panciA0 is getting removed, i want to remove word if it is present not a character
how can i achive this ?

I used `sed` even this is not working for me

```
Current=`sed "s/\bCurrent\b/$Bypass_final/g"`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to replace all required words at once using `sed`, rather than iterating through them and replacing one by one.

```
Profile="panicA2 panicA1 panicA0 gasleakB0"
Bypass="0 panicA1 gasleakB0"

# prepare the regex
Pattern=$(echo "\\b\\("$Bypass"\\)\\s\\?\\b" | sed 's/ /\\\|/g')
echo $Pattern # \b\(0\|panicA1\|gasleakB0\)\s\?\b

echo $Profile | sed "s/$Pattern//g"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
sed "s/[[:<:]]Yourword[[:>:]]/Replacedword/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always match partial words, the following should work as intended.

```
Profile="panicA2 panicA1 panicA0 gasleakB0"
Bypass="0 panicA1 gasleakB0"
Current="$Profile"
for Bypass_final in $Bypass ; do
    if [[ $Current =~ ^$Bypass_final[[:space:]](.*)$ ]] \
        || [[ $Current =~ ^(.*)[[:space:]]$Bypass_final$ ]] \
        || [[ $Current =~ ^(.*)[[:space:]]$Bypass_final[[:space:]](.*)$ ]]; then
        Current=${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:$[${#BASH_REMATCH[*]} - 1]}
    fi
done

echo $Current
```